# 5 Video Game Riddles - What are these Games?

Tags: riddle, video-games

With the bounty ended, and I still haven't gotten the answer, I have awarded the prize to El-Guest. If eventually, I get the answer, I will award the correct person 50 rep as well. Thank you for your answers though.

So, my friend is kind of a video game addict. He knows a lot of obscure video games and I don't think anyone has cracked his riddles yet. He came up with five games that I don't think I've ever heard of. If you think you can crack them, take a shot at it. Please note that, if you do answer one, but not all of them, explicitly state which one you're answering. Also, if you answer all of them, place them chronologically in your answer (don't go and put Number 4 at the top, and Number 1 at the bottom). It'll surprise me if anyone can get all five of them, but here's hoping. Also, he stated as a hint that if you could crack the code in chronological order, the first letter of every video game should spell out

> MJGWB

Good luck.

1. One day, into a mansion, enters a man,
   Then a demon used him for her plan.
   The brother of the man soon came by,
   And he feared his brother may soon die.
   A seemingly benign man turned out to be a traitor,
   But this is revealed not sooner, but much later.
   And the so-called demon who had been sealed away for years
   Is finally free, and leaves behind the blood and tears. SOLVED
2. I am considered the weakest in the trilogy, as I have one less story than the others in the updated versions. However, along with that, I also had the first true bad ending in the series. Of course, every story has a bad ending in this series, but my last story had the first confirmed bad ending. But my successor promised this fact: the bad ending is not the true ending, as proven in the second story in his game. My successor is also the reason why this riddle is not in poetic form, as a character from the third game is a poet. Finally, I must say that while a story is typically chronological, my first story came after the second story. SOLVED
3. The main character in my story came first in a TV show, as well as the villain,
   And yet, not a single character is this tale is human.
   You might think at first that Earth is not a series of floating islands   connected by bridges, and you’d be right,
   But the fifth and final world proves you’re not on Earth, you’re in space, which to you is another plight.
   The game itself is hard to find,
   But you probably still know these characters because they’re somewhere in your mind. SOLVED
4. With just two lines, do you think you can solve this mystery?
   You’re on the case and you’re chasing her through history!  SOLVED
5. Finally, please note that for this game,
   The game has more than one name.
   The king who rules over this whole storybook,
   He has more than just one look.
   His kingdom he rules over with his hand,
   From the computers to a pyramid land.
   The king has the power of fire, like A Zone.
   And yet, he was banished to live alone.
   A world in this tale has many sweets,
   But the desert still has many treats.
   This game has plenty references to others from the same company,
   But it is a good game, too bad the people who know it is not many.  (Still Unsolved)

Hints: These hints are only for 5, since that is the only one remaining.

5.

> While this sequel is not that well-known, the original game was rather successful.

AND (and this is the last hint my friend will give.)

> There are many forks in the road ahead, but only one path leads to a good ending.

Comment: obscure games are the worst to figure out. Is there any timescale for them or has he left that out

Comment: He gave me hints for the remaining three that are left, up above.

Comment: Give more hints!!!

Comment: Sorry we couldn't come up with the final answer in time! I'm going to keep looking...hopefully your friend will have mercy for one more hint! :P

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to consolidate a full answer here, based on the others below. Definitely please upvote all answers that you see as well, because they were crucial to filling out my plurality! :D So thanks to everyone!! 
 
1: (Thanks to @Donalf Deamer)

> [Mario the Music Box](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/MarioTheMusicBox)

2: (Thanks to @sedrick)

> [Phoenix Wright: Justice for All](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_Wright:_Ace_Attorney_%E2%88%92_Justice_for_All)

3:

> [Galactic Taz Ball](http://looneytunes.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Taz_Ball)?

4:

> [Where in Time is Carmen Sandiego?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_in_Time_Is_Carmen_Sandiego%3F_(video_game))

5: (@wolfram42's answer looks like it's bounty-winning)

> [Mario & Luigi: Bowser's Inside Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_%26_Luigi:_Bowser%27s_Inside_Story)

Comment: When I looked up that answer on the internet along with my question, I got a similar result, Where in TIME is Carmen Sandiego, but I'll give you credit for it since I still couldn't come up with an answer close to it.

Comment: Thanks, I've made that fix and linked the page to the game.

Comment: Yes, Galactic Taz Ball was correct. I couldn't hardly find anything on the game, so great job finding it.

Comment: I'm going to unmark this one as the best answer until we get the last two answers in. When we have them, I'll remark it.

Comment: My friend said that 1 and 5 are both incorrect. I asked him if he was certain and he said that for sure, they were incorrect.

Comment: If you could, could you replace one with Mario the Music Box, since that's correct?

Answer (score 8):

The second game is

> Phoenix Wright: Justice for All

I am considered the weakest in the trilogy, as I have one less story than the others in the updated versions.

> It only has 4 cases while the other two games both have 5.

However, along with that, I also had the first true bad ending in the series. Of course, every story has a bad ending in this series, but my last story had the first confirmed bad ending.

> The fourth case had 2 endings, one of them a "good" ending and the other a "bad" ending.

But my predecessor promised this fact: the bad ending is not the true ending, as proven in the second story in his game.

> Mia Fey was the victim in the second case of the first game.

My predecessor is also the reason why this riddle is not in poetic form, as a character from the third game is a poet.

> Not sure about this. Don't know of any poet in the games.

Finally, I must say that while a story is typically chronological, my first story came after the second story.

> The first case (The Lost Turnabout) occurred after the second case (Reunion, and Turnabout).

Also,

> It starts with letter J (Justice)

Comment: I showed my friend this, and he said it was correct. But I made the mistake when I said predecessor. I meant to say successor, so that one's on me.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to take a random stab at Number One, given that it hasn't been answered correctly yet.
Could Number One be...

> Mario The Music Box?

One day, into a mansion, enters a man,
Then a demon used him for her plan.

> This describes Mario perfectly, as he is first to enter the mansion, and is seemingly possessed by a malevolent spirit.

The brother of the man soon came by,
And he feared his brother may soon die.

> This describes Luigi fairly well, as he sees visions of suicide, bloody corpses, and "Mario" constantly killing himself.

A seemingly benign man turned out to be a traitor,
But this is revealed not sooner, but much later.

> This describes Riba, as he is believed to be a nice dude at first, but is revealed late in the game to be the true main antagonist.

And the so-called demon who had been sealed away for years
Is finally free, and leaves behind the blood and tears.

> This is likely Alice, as she is revealed to be the spirit possessing Mario, but in the true ending, she leaves behind the mansion and this earthly realm.

Comment: Just seeing the name, I didn't go through the spoilers as I have played this game before and never finished it. My friend said that this was correct, so great job!

Answer (score 4):

Alright, so I'm going to guess for 5:

> Mario & Luigi: Bowser's Inside Story

Some reasoning:

Finally, please note that for this game,
The game has more than one name.

> The name is divided into two parts, and in japan it is called Mario & Luigi RPG 3

The king who rules over this whole storybook,
He has more than just one look.

> In the game Bowser takes on many forms including a dark and giant version

His kingdom he rules over with his hand,
From the computers to a pyramid land.

> I believe there is both a computer land and a pyramid land in the game

The king has the power of fire, like A Zone.

> Bowser breathes fire

And yet, he was banished to live alone.

> It's Bowser, he is always banished to be alone.

A world in this tale has many sweets,
But the desert still has many treats.

> Like in all mario games sweets are prevalent throughout. Sweet syrup is a healing item and there is star candy

This game has plenty references to others from the same company,

> Mario always makes references to other games

Comment: This is a great answer, I hope it's correct! (+1) from me :)

Comment: My friend said this one was also incorrect, sorry. I remember playing through this one though, but good try anyways. I really did think this one was correct, and you explained why too, so good job.

Answer (score 3):

Could #5 be:

> Sonic Lost World?

Mainly I'm thinking because of the

> Desert Ruins

level but also the king, the sweets, pyramid and zone references in your clues.

Hope I'm right!!

Comment: So, my friend said this was wrong, but he did credit you on the zone method, as it was a crucial clue, but for a different game.

Answer (score 3):

## 5 is

> Bubble Symphony, a sequel to Bubble Bobble

Finally, please note that for this game,
The game has more than one name.

> It is known as Bubble Symphony or Bubble Bobble II

The king who rules over this whole storybook,
He has more than just one look.

> The main boss of the game is released while the main characters are reading books, and transports them to Storybook World

His kingdom he rules over with his hand,
From the computers to a pyramid land.

> The game includes areas such as Computer Land and Pyramid Land

The king has the power of fire, like A Zone.
And yet, he was banished to live alone.

> There is a Fire Zone, but otherwise this one is a bit weak

A world in this tale has many sweets,
But the desert still has many treats.

> Other worlds include Dessert Land and Treasure Desert

This game has plenty references to others from the same company,
But it is a good game, too bad the people who know it is not many.

> A sequel to the popular Bubble Bobble, it includes references to other Taito games

There are many forks in the road ahead, but only one path leads to a good ending.

> The game includes a branching level structure

Answer (score 2):

Since the other 3 were answered, here are my guesses for 1 and 5:

1.

> Middle of Nowhere

5.

> Black and White 2

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Great answers! I hope that they're right! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, my friend denied both answers. I mean I looked into them and they were good answers, but he said neither were correct. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

For # 5 I'm going to guess

> Super Smash Bros Brawl

The game has more than one name.

> SSB, SSB Melee, SSB Ultimate, etc

The king who rules over this whole storybook,

> Tabuu is the main hidden enemy ruling in the Subspace Emissary (Single-player storyline part of game). He is subspace and creates an army to take over everything.

He has more than just one look.

> Tabuu can grow into a large size, can transform to have wings, can transform himself into a gold cage or giant blade.

His kingdom he rules over with his hand,

> In the Subspace Emissary, Tabuu controlled the Master Hand and used it as a mouthpiece to call the shots of the take-over. Directing and leading Bowser, Ganondorf, Wario and other villains through Master Hand.

From the computers to a pyramid land.

> There's a desert area and robot/computer area in the Subspace Emissary.

The king has the power of fire, like A Zone.

> The Flat Zone is a stage and it has parts that can burn you. The main character for that stage (Mr. Game and Watch) also has a move that can burn you. Tabuu has moves that cause explosions, fire bursting out when it hits, which can burn you.

And yet, he was banished to live alone.

> Tabuu is the embodiment of subspace and therefor cannot leave subspace. Nothing lives there, so he created a spectral army to turn people of the world into trophies and bring them into subspace.

A world in this tale has many sweets,

> In the subspace emissary, there are areas that have Poppants, which are enemies that drop candy as they run away. These candies can be consumed and will heal you.

But the desert still has many treats.

> The desert area has hidden areas where special trophies and extra un-lockable characters can be found.

This game has plenty references to others from the same company,

> SSB has a cast of characters from Mario, Zelda, Pokemon, etc.

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch though, to argue that the game you chose starts with the letter "B."

Comment: I will say that this answer was surprisingly a possible alternative according to my friend, and that if the name were different in other countries this answer would be the perfect alternative to the answer. It wasn't correct, but he said that the only reason this wasn't correct was because of the name not changing depending on location (it is commonly known as Brawl but nothing else in other countries).

Comment: @KingDedede'sSecretAssistant Ahh, I was thinking of it as a series name. There's a bunch of different iterations of the game.

Comment: @peaceoutside Since there are so many different iterations of the game, when people ask if you wanna play SSB they don't even refer to that part. They call the different iterations Melee, Brawl, or Project M. I was just referring to that. But I can see how it would seem a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Damn this is what I first thought of when I read it!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it!!

Is it

> Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild???

Finally, please note that for this game,
The game has more than one name.

> Legend of Zelda and Breath of the Wild

The king who rules over this whole storybook,

> Yes, there is a king.

From the computers to a pyramid land.

> Very Zelda reference as Triforce has pyramids

The king has the power of fire, like A Zone.

> Zones in this game for sure.

A world in this tale has many sweets,
But the desert still has many treats.

> You can cook and make desserts in the game.

Boy, I hope this one is it! If not, I'm pretty convinced it could be another in the series.

Comment: I'm sorry. My friend said it's not Legend of Zelda at all. Good try though.

Answer (score 0):

Could number 5 be

> Breath of fire?

If this is correct, I'll elaborate.

Comment: It's not. Thanks for trying though

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an answer for #5:

> Sonic and the Secret Rings

Finally, please note that for this game,
The game has more than one name.

> originally announced as Sonic Wild Fire, also known as Hyper Sonic, before settling on the final name.

The king who rules over this whole storybook,

> one of two games in the Sonic Storybook series.  King Shahryar is king over the Arabian Nights storybook

He has more than just one look.

> He's Doctor Eggman in a different outfit

His kingdom he rules over with his hand,
From the computers to a pyramid land.

> Arabian Nights is a pyramid Land, and Doctor Eggman is more normally in control of a hight-tech empire.

The king has the power of fire, like A Zone.

> there is a fire-themed Evil Foundry zone, and the main villain has some fire powers, but this one seems a bit weak, as the king himself doesn't have fire powers.

And yet, he was banished to live alone.

> in the end, the main villain is locked away into a permanent prison.  Still not the king?

A world in this tale has many sweets,
But the desert still has many treats.

> honestly not about this one.

This game has plenty references to others from the same company,
But it is a good game, too bad the people who know it is not many.

> Includes a number of other sonic characters pushed into Arabian Nights roles.
>  Not well known and has even been delisted

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old riddle, but since social distancing means a lot more screen time, I just stumbled upon it. And #5 immediately struck me as

> Populous

so I just had to post a guess.

This doesn't begin with the correct letter. But there is the second sequel

> Populous: The Beginning

that kind of does.

However, I never played that one. From what I can gather right now, this sequel no longer fits the hints properly. But since I don't know for sure and I feel the original fits rather fine, I'll still guess.

If you are still around and should I be correct, I can elaborate on the details, at least in reference to the original.